# What stages can I play the "Step:" songs on?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

After completing Subspace Emissary (Super Smash Bros. Brawl), I unlocked and was presented with four or five music tracks. A few of them were the Step tracks (like "Step: Subspace" and "Step: The Plain") and a boss battle song or two (esp. the song during the Tabuu fight).

I thought these songs would play on Battlefield or Final Destination, but they aren't listed there.  I can't find them on any stages, actually.

So does anyone know where these songs went? If I can't play them in a stage, where can I listen to them, at least?

Comment: Most likely they can only be played from the music player screen and aren't on any maps. However I can't confirm this so I'm not posting it as an answer

Comment: @DJ Spicy Deluxe-Levi That music player screen! I totally forgot about that, thanks.  I haven't unlocked all stages yet, I'll check to confirm once I have.

Answer (score 1):

The only place you can play the "Step" SSE Exclusive songs are in custom stages under the "Super Smash Bros Brawl" section while you are choosing your music. The stage editor is in the vault (the green section on main menu).

"Step" songs include:

- Step: Cave
- Step: The Plain
- Step(s): Subspace Ver. 1, 2, and 3